# Run shell script as root user while being a regular user

Tags: 20.04

My goal: I have a bash script that needs to be run as a root user in a way that wouldn't be killable by a regular user--me. However, as a regular user, I need to be able to start the script (there might be cases where this unkillable script shouldn't be executed).

Is there a way to achieve it?

**I imagine the following workflow**: I log in to my regular account, execute the bash script, which then starts a specific program. This program becomes unkillable by me because it was started from an administrator account.

**The way I do it now**: I log in to my regular user, do `su admin` and insert a complicated password, and run the program in unattached way (i.e. with `&`). I then close the terminal and continue with the opened program and go on with my day.

**What I tried**: grant my user rights to execute the script created by the admin, but this of course makes me able to kill the script afterwards, since I own that process. I would like that the process would be owned by another user..

Comment: Running the program in an unttached way with & and then closing the terminal? That also closes the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a helper script and have it executed every 1 minute via root's crontab. This would act as a bridge between root and the regular user.

#### bridge.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME="/tmp/starter-file-with-unique-name"

if [ -f $FILENAME ] ;
then
    /usr/bin/specific-program
    rm $FILENAME
    ## you could do some logging here if you want
fi
```

Now your regular used just needs to create that starter file (eg. `touch /tmp/starter-file-with-unique-name`). Within the next 60 seconds, cron will execute `bridge.sh`, which will detect the starter file and then execute the specific program.

#### crontab entry example

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/bridge.sh
```

#### Can't wait up to 60 seconds?

If you want to have your specific program started immediately, you can add a loop to `bridge.sh`, with something like `sleep 1`. In this case root should not execute the script every 1 minute, but only once, maybe use `@reboot` in crontab, or create a systemd service for it.

Comment: Oh this is clever. I will give it a try and mark the question as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it using setuid bit, but not directly, as setuid bit is ignored on shell scripts. Setuid bit works only on binary executable programs, and makes the program run under the user who is owner of the executable file. So if your script were a binary program, you would need to make the file owned by your admin user, and then set the setuid bit (`chmod u+s filename`).

For a shell script and not a binary program, you need an intermediate binary program (so called **wrapper**) that runs your script - it's the only thing it does. If you set the wrapper program setuid, then your script will be run from within that program with the same permissions.

Look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346404/is-there-something-as-events-in-ubuntu/1346583#1346583), where I explained in detail how to create such a binary wrapper program.